# Mouseover during scroll

Tags: javascript

This fiddle doesn't detect the mouseover on a span if during the scroll the mouse pass over the span : http://jsfiddle.net/S7tnB/
How can I detect it?
I test on firefox 12, on a OSX lion.

**EDIT :** I thought of something that could work : `onscroll`, we test if the position of the cursor is in the area of the span! But I had another problem, `e.pageX` don't work when I write `onscroll=theFunction(event)`. If you solve this, it is like you solve the main problem.

Comment: That's a pretty complicated thing to do. Are you sure you need this feature?

Comment: It detects the mouseover just fine in IE8, too. Maybe you should tell us which browser and OS to test on.  Also, did you really mean to detect the span moving underneath the mouse pointer when you activate the scroll bar?  If that's what you mean, I didn't get that behavior.  Please clarify.

Comment: It doesn't work for me at all in latest Chrome on Win7.

Comment: I don't know if you are doing it write but the thing is to scroll normaly and at the same time the cursor pass over the span

Comment: I fail to see the point in this. and if it does not work, I would guess that's just how that browser acts.

Comment: FWIW I noticed on Firefox 13.01, Windows XP, if I try the original poster's fiddle, I reproduce his problem. But if I just add an onscroll event (doing nothing) then I start getting mouseovers as well. I'm using the mouse wheel to scroll, keeping the mouse pointer still. See: http://jsfiddle.net/aVh9d/4/